# CSS Vertical Progress Bar

Tags: jquery, html, css

**Vertical Progress Bar**

---

The proper styling of this bar requires:

- the progress bar must be covered by an element holding a number of cross-bars.
- no images (i.e. using an image of the cross bars).
- the progress bar must be attached to the bottom of the origin, and extend upward.
- most importantly, the progress bar's wrapper width must remain dynamic (%), not defined statically.
- the bar's width stretches depending on the width of its container component
- A pure CSS solution is best, but JQuery is fair game.

---

[image]

---

**Progress Bar HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="attendance">
        <p class="title">attendance</p>
        <div class="attendance-bar">
            <div class="attendance-level"></div>
            <div class="attendance-cage-css">
                <div class="crossbar-1"></div>
                <div class="crossbar-2"></div>
                <div class="crossbar-3"></div>
                <div class="crossbar-4"></div>
                <div class="crossbar-5"></div>
                <div class="crossbar-6"></div>
                <div class="crossbar-7"></div>
                <div class="crossbar-8"></div>
                <div class="crossbar-9"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

**JS Fiddle including HTML markup & all CSS classes:**

http://jsfiddle.net/q2SAK/

**My Progress:**

http://jsfiddle.net/q2SAK/2/

---

**Bonus:**

I've implemented unique classes for each crossbar in order to achieve the increasing margins between them shown above. Thumbs up if you know how to achieve the effect without the classes. Show it in your JS Fiddle.

---

Comment: is this a challenge or are you gonna show what you already have?

Comment: What I have doesn't work at all, I was going to let it be a challenge, if that isn't breaking the rules. @Spokey

Comment: Your question is written and formatted well. However, it would be helpful to see what you tried and specifically what went wrong with your attempt.

Comment: Ok, I'll add my JSFiddle! @showdev

Comment: I've added my progress. The first problem I run into (other than anchoring the bar to the bottom) is the absolute positioning of the bars in combination with their dynamic widths. @Spokey

Comment: I think you can handle it from here, you mostly need to set the `position` of the parents in oder for `position:absolute;` to take the width from the parent. http://jsfiddle.net/q2SAK/4/

Comment: @Spokey Oh cool! I'd never been able to figure out how to use the parents' sized/position with absolutely positioned child elements. So relative parent position is what allows you to take it's size/position  with the absolutely positioned child element?

Comment: Yeah in it's most basic. This method allows you to position `absolute child elements` relative to their `parent` and not to the `body`.

Comment: does the whole line of parent (and grand-parent) elements up to the `body` need to be `relative`,or just a single parent? @Spokey

Comment: usually only the parent of the element with `position:absolute;` needs it. But depending on the structure it may go all the way up to `body`. I didn't really look in your fiddle and just added it everywhere to make sure :D (you don't actually need it for container and attendance-bat)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Challenge accepted!**

I took your fiddle and created [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/imtheman/5E2q2/3/) from it. It's a very simple demonstration of what you can do with it. You click the "Click me and it goes from 5px to 200px. Of course you can make it so that it increments by a certain number everytime. This is the just of it though. I just posted on here some of the changes I made, the full code is on the jsfiddle

**Update:** [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/imtheman/5E2q2/5/) one goes up by 5px everytime you click it. Of course you'd need to tell it went to stop, otherwise it'd go on forever.

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="attendance">
            <p class="title">ATTENDANCE</p>
            <div class="attendance-bar">                
                <div class="attendance-level">
                    <div class="bar-1"></div>
                    <div class="bar-2"></div>
                    <div class="bar-3"></div>
                    <div class="bar-4"></div>
                    <div class="bar-5"></div>
                    <div class="bar-6"></div>
                    <div class="bar-7"></div>
                    <div class="bar-8"></div>
                    <div class="bar-9"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="attendance-cage-css"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<div id="changeatt" style="top:50px; left: 200px; position: absolute">Click me</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container{
    width:100px;
    height:350px;
    position: absolute;
}

.attendance-bar{
    float:left;
    width:90%;
    margin:0px 5% 0px 5%;
    height:260px;
    background-color:#2f2f2f;
}

.attendance-cage-css{
    width:80px;
    float:left;
    background-color:#6ae719;
    height:5px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.bar-1,.bar-2,.bar-3,.bar-4,.bar-5,.bar-6,.bar-7,.bar-8,.bar-9{
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#1f1f1f;
    height:10px;
    z-index: 9999;
}

.attendance-level{
    float:left;
    height:100px;
    width:80px;
    z-index: 9999;
    position: absolute;
    top:60px;
}
```

**JQuery**

```
$('#changeatt').click(function(){
    $('.attendance-cage-css').css('height', '200px');
});
```

**Update**
If you want a max height, I would recommend something like below. It will check to make sure the height of the progress bar does not exceed that of the progress bar container.

```
if($('.attendance-cage-css').height() < $('.attendance-bar').height()){
    $('.attendance-cage-css').css('height', $('.attendance-cage-css').height() + 5);
}
```

Note: If you want the bar to reach max height, you must make the height of the container a multiple of which you are increasing the progress bar. For example, if you are increasing the bar by 5px then the height of the container should be 260px, 265px, etc.

Comment: I was playing around with your fiddle and when you click, the height adds on forever. How would you add a maximum height to the jquery so that the green won't overlap the word 'attendance'?

Comment: I updated the answer to provide and example of how to do that.

Comment: @imtheman How to put the snippet into the codepen?