# Progress Bar Wobble Effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, progress-bar

**Wobbling Vertical Progress Bar**

---

I learned how to build a neat, dynamically sized vertical progress bar with cross-bars in [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22337851/css-vertical-progress-bar?noredirect=1#comment33950248_22337851).

Now, I want to make it fun!

---

The bar's wobble function should:

- take 4 parameters: `element` , `height` , `speed` , & `random`
- wobble the `element` height percentage with a customizable, randomized factor
- keep track of the elements's true height, which can change at any time!
- use an event (in the Fiddle, I supply an input and button) to set the true height to a new value, and animate to that height.

> I'm looking for the simplest answer. Please explain how you did it, so that we JS newbies can learn tricks! Posting a Bounty of +50 to the best answer.

---

[image]

---

Bonus:

- change the bars's background color value based on the bar's true height. Red is 0%, Yellow is 50%, and Green is 100%;

> If your function does this too, I'll add a +100 Bounty to your answer instead.

---

[Template Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q2SAK/5/)

---

[My Progress](http://jsfiddle.net/q2SAK/5/)

> I'm asking this question because I don't know how to do this yet.
>   But, I'm going to try it from what I've learned so far, and keep my
>   progress posted here.

Comment: So... you want the stack to wobble? Do you mean when it jumps it does a bounce effect and then settles down and then if it changes again it does the same thing?

Comment: The bar. Whatever element is passed to the function should wobble. The nature of the wobble is up to you. The purpose is to make the bar look fun and dynamic. @jsve

Comment: i think this is possible in the most simple way by making a transparently layered png of your gradient. the bars being transparent. then have a div behind it, and animate the height with jquery animate and the color with jquery ui animate: bounce effect on completion. if i had more time i'd do it for you, but i don't. kudos to the guys below for taking the time and having made sterling effort. +1's all round.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So here's my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q2SAK/8/) take on it.

Comments should be self explanatory. I had to add JQuery UI for the animation effects with easing. I'm not sure what you meant by `random`, but speed should be all you need to change.

[image: WobbleBar] Sorry, no animation in the screenshots.

Comment: The animation in this one is robust. Nice. Can you show a version that wobbles a bit, constantly?

Comment: Constantly as in.. never ending? Try checking out [SO: How to make a jQuery infinite animation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713477/how-to-make-a-jquery-infinite-animation) and work on integrating that into the code. All it is doing in this case would be to just add `setInterval( updateAttendance, 700 );` inside the jQuery.ready

Comment: That will probably not change the level on a consistent basis (also `this` will be not defined), so you'll probably want to create another function that changes the height of `$('.level')` by a bit so you see an animation. [JSFiddle Updated](http://jsfiddle.net/q2SAK/9/)

Answer (score 7):

Really enjoyed playing with this, so thank you :) I took a different approach but with much less code. I think I went a bit overboard with the colors, if needed I can change it back to red yellow green.

http://jsfiddle.net/3wN77/23/

```
$('#change-height').on('click', function() {
    var element = $('.attendance-level');
    var height = parseInt( $('#true-height').val() ); // %
    var speed = 1000;  //ms
    var random = 50; //px
    bar_wobble( element, height, speed, random );
});

function bar_wobble(element, height, speed, random) {
    //set the color
    $(element).css('-webkit-filter','hue-rotate('+ 140*(250/height) +'deg)'); //red = 0 deg, green = 140deg

    //wibbly wobbly timey wimey stuff
    height = height/100*250;
    var number_of_wobbles = 3;
    for(var i=1; i<=number_of_wobbles; i++)
    {    $(element).animate({ height: (height + random/i )+'px'}, speed/(number_of_wobbles*2 + 1));
         $(element).animate({ height: (height - random/i )+'px'}, speed/(number_of_wobbles*2 + 1));
        console.log( {i: i, random_i: random/i, random:random, height:height } );
    }
    $(element).animate({ height: height+'px'}, speed/(number_of_wobbles*2 + 1));
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Yours is among the shortest, simplest answers, but I think you made one mistake. The hue rotate is a simple way to change the colors, but it isn't cross browser compatible yet, and I would not be possible to change between the two colors I have here without going through the whole spectrum the way this solution does. Great job on simplicity though.

Comment: This is the best solution I've seen on this thread. +1 just for the efforts!

Answer (score 5):

Don't think StackOverflow is meant for these kind of 'questions', but oh well, felt like it, so made a far more extensive answer than a sane person would.

Let me start with a couple of technologies I incorporated and their justification

- SVG, it feels terribly wrong when DOM is used to shape an image. Either actual images should be used for the background/foreground, or one should use something like SVG instead of DOM. The disadvantage of SVG is that it can only provide uniform scaling.
- X-Tags, X-tags is a Web Components Custom Element polyfill developed by Mozilla. It allows us to write something like

  ```
  <x-bar id="test"></x-bar>
  ```

  And then do

  ```
  var xbar1 = document.getElementById("test");
  xbar1.value = 10;
  xbar1.speed = 2;
  xbar1.wobble = 10;
  xbar1.effect= "dampen";
  ```

  Cool right? This however means you will first need to read the documentation [here](http://www.x-tags.org/docs). Before you will be able to understand the code.
- Javascript for the animations: Although you could make some elemantary wobble using CSS3 animations, the requirement for the control over it and the colour change requirement makes one choose for Javascript.
- Two wobble effects are incorporated, a simple `y=sin(t)` and a more complexed dampened wave. One could easily add other waves as well, but these seemed to be the most reasonably interesting ones.
- Regarding the code to calculate the colour. I am simply splitting the bar in two halves, for the top half I define a colour range from green to orange and for the second half from orange to red. Next in the code I 'find the point' between those two colours depending on how filled the bar is. (E.g. if we're at 80% filled of the total bar, it means that we're at 60% of the top half, so we take that point between orange and green)

As the code itself is over 200 lines long I will refrain from posting it here and you can find it on [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vWHG7/6/).

Comment: Now that, sir, is fancy. SVG always seemed to me like some weird compensation side piece of web design. Now, thanks to you, I'm going learn it. The smoothness and varation in the outcome of this is nice. I'm reading about the X-tags as well now.

Comment: Is Using SVG more efficient for processing than using the DOM in this situation?

Comment: Also, as I tinker with this, I notice that transitioning between two height values is a jagged, forced process. In LaughDonor's method of achieving this effect, entering a new value results in a smooth transition to the new height. How would I fix that in your script?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Well, it's mostly a cleanness issue for me. DOM is about structuring data, css is about presenting it, svg is for *dynamic) vector images, gif, jpg and png are for bitmap images. So I look at your sidebar and it's definitely an image, as it has to be dynamic I decided to go for svg. So is it more efficient? In this case probably about the same efficiency, but once you need polygons etc. this is the only way to go.

Comment: No, you're right, I didn't program in a state transition as it's quite complex to make it work in combination with a custom 'wobbling' formula. You can see how easy it is to mess up an unstructured solution here http://jsfiddle.net/q2SAK/9/ , but either way, let me outline how you would approach such a problem

Comment: First you would have to keep a state for each bar, being either `transition` or `wobble`. Whenever a height change is set it would need to calculate the difference in heights and store that information (and set state to `transition`). During the transition state the `calculateheight` function should use that information to calculate the transition and then in the `wobble` state do what the code is doing now.